# emacs orgmode files rendering and reminders

Tags: org-mode

I'm receiving task/todo lists in this format ([orgmode](https://orgmode.org/)) .
Emacs is useful for creating and editing this, but useless for end users who want to have well rendered lists/sublists (similar to MS Outlook tasks style or any other desktop organizer) and of course the primary function for any organizer software: flexible desktop reminders.

Is there some GUI software for the work with this format, for any OS?

Comment: What is **this** format? There is no link, no explanation.

Comment: added the link to initial post